# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function $('#loader').hide()

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add my page to a loading spinner. I want to hide spinner when page loaded. I want to show that when button clicked and i want to hide again when json process is finished. I can't continue because I got an error even in the first step. Here is the code i got in the first step :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

All HTML, CSS and Javascript codes are below:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      $('#loader').hide();

     })
```

```css
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 32px);
    left: calc(50% - 32px);
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    perspective: 800px;
  }
  
  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;  
  }
  
  .inner.one {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  .inner.two {
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
    border-right: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  .inner.three {
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
    border-top: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-one {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-two {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-three {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  #loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    }
  #loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 240px;
    z-index: 100;
    }
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="inner one"></div>
    <div class="inner two"></div>
    <div class="inner three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery, is the library properly installed?

Comment: Where did you include jQuery? What does `console.log($)` reveal?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using jquery, so make sure you have added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `head` tag.

Also change `$('#loader') to $('.loader')` because there isn't any div with id loader.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like your using Vanilla JS, so you need to use querySelector, or otherwise if you're using jQuery, so you need to call the jQuery library at your header.

so incase your using the Vanila JS so you can call it like this

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      setTimeout( () => {document.querySelector('.loader').style = 'display:none;'}, 2000);

     })
```

```css
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 32px);
    left: calc(50% - 32px);
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    perspective: 800px;
  }
  
  .inner {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;  
  }
  
  .inner.one {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  .inner.two {
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
    border-right: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  .inner.three {
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
    border-top: 3px solid green;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-one {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-two {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate-three {
    0% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  #loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
    }
  #loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 240px;
    z-index: 100;
    }
```

```html
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="inner one"></div>
    <div class="inner two"></div>
    <div class="inner three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. i'm using Timeout with 2seconds because no thing to load.